# Create iOS Action Extension with no UI

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I am trying to create an Action Extension similar to the system "Copy" action available in iOS.
I found different answers saying it's not possible to have non-fullscreen UI, but according to [Apple Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html) it is possible to have no UI (like in the Copy action, I presume).

> Action (iOS and macOS; UI and non-UI variants)

I have tried creating a transparent view, but the result is always a fullscreen black overlay.
I have already specified `NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation` to `NO` in my `Info.plist`, but nothing changes.

Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: Can you please share us your code?

Comment: I have added my own answer with some code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question: it is actually possible to create a non-UI Action Extension on iOS by assigning the property [NSExtensionPrincipalClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW16) to a class implementing a [NSExtensionRequestHandling](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensionrequesthandling) protocol.

Example:

```
class ActionRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

    var extensionContext: NSExtensionContext?

    func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {
        // Do not call super in an Action extension with no user interface
        self.extensionContext = context

        // Do stuff with the context

    }
}
```

The easiest way to create an extension like this is to add a new target (File > New > Target), select Action Extension and then select **No User Interface** in the **Action Type**.

Comment: Hi @pasine. Could you please let me know if it is possible to invoke this extension programmatically from the containing app?

Comment: Sorry, it's something I haven't tried, so I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> In iOS, an Action extension:
>
> - Helps users view the current document in a different way
> - **Always appears in an action sheet or full-screen modal view**
> - Receives selected content only if explicitly provided by the host app

Comment: So, is the no UI option available on MacOS only? Does this mean I can have a non-fullscreen action sheet?

Comment: Yes, it only exists on MacOS. Yes, as per the documents you can have an action sheet which was never a fullscreen.

Comment: Apparently, non-UI variant also exists on iOS.