# Is there a way to prevent Finder window from popping up when executing a Mac app action extension?

Tags: swift, macos, finder, finder-extension

I recently added a few action extensions to my Mac app. They work fine and I display their UI and progress in a dedicated window. For some reason though, Finder also open a window where it displays the process name and an undefined progress bar and says "estimating time remaining. [image: image of finder window automatically popped up saying estimating time remaining and process name]

I've looked everywhere, but can't find documentation on if this can prevented from popping up or how it could be controlled. Easy way to recreate is to start a project with one of Apple's template action extensions in Xcode or download samples here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/app_extensions/add_functionality_to_finder_with_action_extensions

Comment: Can it be related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620639/create-ios-action-extension-with-no-ui

Comment: Same problem domain as in action extensions, but didn't really see specific answer there. Also, I need to have a UI for my app, so removing UI (the one I provide) isn't really an option. @d.c.